# Responsive Video and Parent container height

Tags: html, css, video, responsive-design, html5-video

I have the following markup:

```css
.jumbotron {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -101;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
}
.jumbotron video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -100;
}
.video-content {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class='jumbotron'>
  <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
    <source src="https://ia800201.us.archive.org/12/items/BigBuckBunny_328/BigBuckBunny_512kb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="video.ogv" type="video/ogv" />
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
  </video>
  <div class='video-content'>
    <h1>Welcome to the Site</h1>
    <p>This is just a test but it shows a background video</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-12'>
      <h2>Section Heading</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My question is around the responsiveness of the `video` background. When I make the viewport smaller the `video` eventually begins to shrink and the parent div remains longer then it - resulting in an unwanted red background.

How can I ensure the parent div scales with the size of the video? So that when I bring it right down to `> 480px` the `h2` tag will be right below the video.

You can see a a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5fq927dL/)

Answer (score 2):

This will work for you :)

```
.jumbotron {
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.jumbotron video {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50%; 
    right: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(50%) translateY(50%);
    transform: translateX(50%) translateY(50%);
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -1000;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I like this solution, can you explain what is happening here? I am slightly confused!

Answer (score 1):

you can change the fixed `height` to `padding-bottom` in `.jumbotron`

```css
.jumbotron {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  /* 16:9 */
  height: 0;
  background: red;
}
.jumbotron video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%
}
.video-content {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class='jumbotron'>
  <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
    <source src="https://ia800201.us.archive.org/12/items/BigBuckBunny_328/BigBuckBunny_512kb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="video.ogv" type="video/ogv" />
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
  </video>
  <div class='video-content'>
    <h1>Welcome to the Site</h1>
    <p>This is just a test but it shows a background video</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-12'>
      <h2>Section Heading</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood. I made the video fill the screen, by changing its height and width to the viewport size. But needs to keep the aspect ratio.

```
.jumbotron video {
  ...
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  ...
}
```